# Show image on infowindow Google Maps from BLOB data

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have some problem, i want to show image from my Database which is have a BLOB data type, here's my code

```
var gambar  = new Array();

<?php include_once("koneksi.php"); 
$query3 = "SELECT a.gambarbyte from asset a";
$result3 = mysql_query($query3);
$coba1=array();
$i=0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result3, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $coba1[$i]=$row[0];
$i++;  
}
?>
gambar = <?php echo json_encode($coba1); ?>;
var contentString = '';

//the Problem Is in Here

contentString +=  '<br><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'+ gambar[0] + ' />';
infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
infoWindow.open(map);
```

i want to set value var contentstring for infowindow with image that i load from Database, anyone help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing ", src does not end.

```
contentString +=  '<br><img src="data:image/png;base64,'+ base64blob + '"/>';
```

Here is a working JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/B2ZF3

Comment: it still doesn work, when i change to
    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($gambar[0]); ?>" />
it work, but still i need to do in javascript variable to manipulated some data. Any Suggestion

Comment: does browser app affected the result??

Comment: ok, now i know my fault, i forget to insert base64_encode when query and store to $coba1. Anyway Thanks broo